# hibernate one field as part of composite key in few relations

Tags: java, hibernate

So the problem is how to define company source system column as a part of many composite keys to have cascade all turned on. In this example I have entities type and status that are related with some client entity. Every entity has global identity "company_source_system". In client I dont want to replicate this column for each relation so I created only one column and that's the problem because as u can see both join columns annotation includes "company_source_system" so I need to add insertable/updatable = false(and that breaks saving type and status at end of transaction, even if those fields are set, hiberante not insert those values...). So how to get rid of insertable/updatable = false in this example? I want to have automaticly saved type/status...

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(insertable = false, insertable = false, name = "type", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    @JoinColumn(insertable = false, insertable = false, name = "company_source_system", referencedColumnName = "company_own_id")
})
private Type type;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(insertable = false, insertable = false, name = "status", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    @JoinColumn(insertable = false, insertable = false, name = "company_source_system", referencedColumnName = "company_own_id")
})
private Status status;
```

error when I'am setting insertable/updatatble = true

```
Repeated column in mapping for entity: Client column: company_source_system (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

Comment: Can you post how are you creating the composite key, and the errors, also check this http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/composite-primary-keys-in-hibernate/

Comment: About composite keys declaration is difficult because I can define it as EmedablleId or add ID annotation to few fields. Doesn't matter, most important is to make somehow to have automatic cascade...

Comment: I think it's telling you to put `insertable = false` and `updatable = false` on the `@OneToMany` side of the mapping, not on the `@ManyToOne` side.

Comment: Dont think so. Because I'am adding true true in code above. And type/status dont have relation to client in theirs java entities.